# Help me grab a value from a multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can't seem to get this value.  here is the array:

```
[1596] => Array
(
    [entry_id] => 1596
    [title] => This is the article title
    [url_title] => url-title-here
    [status] => open
    [entry_date] => 1304544513
    [alt_title] => 
    [article_summary] => This is the article summary
    [article_intro] => This is the article intro
    [article_image] => 
    [article_body] => This is the article body
    [article_media_id] => 1
    [article_videos] => 
    [article_media] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [row_id] => 3730
                    [row_order] => 0
                    [col_id_7] => image
                    [col_id_12] => right
                    [col_id_8] => 9781400068609.jpg
                    [col_id_9] => 
                    [col_id_10] => 
                    [col_id_54] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to build a URL using

```
'http://www.domain.com/uploads/media/'.$entry['entry_id']['article_media'][0]['col_id_8']
```

but it keeps giving me a '1' at the end of that image value. it should be 9781400068609.jpg, right?  What do I have wrong?

Comment: The code you've posted looks right. Can you comment out the code to verify that the 1 isn't coming from somewhere else?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['entry_id']` is derailing your path.  You'll want to refer to the top-level key by its number (probably in a variable) like this:

```
$entry_id = 1596;
$valueYouWant = $entry[$entry_id]['article_media'][0]['col_id_8'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your array is called `entry`, then

```
$entry['entry_id'] == 1596
```

you must write instead:

```
$entry['article_media'][0]['col_id_8']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the ID 1596 not 'entry_id' if `$entry` is the array holding all entries

```
$entry[1596]['article_media'][0]['col_id_8']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$entryId = 1596;
$entries[$entryId]['article_media'][0]['col_id_8']
```